# how to play multi videos in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming

I want to stream multi videos in Android, I used videoview, when I use video with resolution 360p, it worked fine , but when I use a video with resolution 720p or 1080, just one video worked, and it shows  can't play this video for the other videos.
please help me!
this is the code:

```
String VideoURL ;
VideoView videoView;
VideoView imgv1,imgv2;

 imgv2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView3); 
 imgv1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
 videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1); 

 Intent intent= getIntent();
 VideoURL = intent.getStringExtra("path");
 video = Uri.parse(VideoURL); 

 mediaController = new MediaController(MyActivity.this);
 videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    imgv1.setVideoURI(video);
    imgv2.setVideoURI(video);


    videoView.start();
    imgv1.start();
    imgv2.start();
```

Comment: please share your code